# How can I enable SNMP on latest Time Capsule 802.11ac?

Tags: airport, time-capsule, snmp

There is a known issue that latest Time Capsule and Airport Base stations have SNMP disabled. But SNMP ports 161 and 162 are still reserved by Time Capsule for SNMP. It leads to the question: Is there someone who was able to enable SNMP on the latest models of TC and AE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the [AirPort Extreme 802.11ac](https://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/airport_extreme_80211ac_setup.pdf) nor the [AirPort Time Capsule 802.11ac](https://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/airport_time_capsule_80211ac_setup.pdf) appear to support SNMP or syslog data to maintain or monitor these devices.

You'd have to load some custom firmware or discover an older management tool that can convince them to configure either of those services. Nothing I can find from Apple shows that either functionality remains on the current AirPort line of hardware.

Answer (score 1):

With the old 5.6.1 airport utility the options in the tool is available. On my time capsule the snmp-options are missing but the syslog-option is there. Not available in the OSX most recent version of airport-utility though. .. found the old version here: https://www.naschenweng.info/2017/02/24/enable-missing-snmp-airport-express-monitoring-librenms/